# Magento 2.4 Checkout error Failed to load the "Magento_Checkout/shipping" template

Tags: shipping-address, magento-upgrade, checkout-page, magento24

I've some error console bus in checkout page when upgrading core.
Does anybody know where this bug is from?

```
Failed to load the "Magento_Checkout/shipping" template requested by "checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress".
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

check your custom shipping.html file:
app/code/YOUR_VENDOR/MODULE_NAME/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

In this file something is not correct.
The newest Magento 2.4.x seems to be more strict about that.

For start you can just clean that file to the empty state and refresh the page. You should now see no more errors. You should investigate which content of this file is causing problems. The possible causes include:

- incorrect attribute name for some html tag
- self-closing tags like `<span /> or <div />`, whereas they should be `<div></div>, <span></span>`
- something open without closing, etc.

Comment: Thank you,This guide me to fix my issue on checkout page customization in 2.4.4 version.

Comment: In my case, it was as simple as an extra *<!-- /ko -->* that should not have been there. After removing said line, the error disappeared.